# Adding an if statement in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

From this dataframe:

```
tree       cues                        directions   thresholds   exits
 1   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;0;1;0.5
 2   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI                 >;>;>     126;29;29.7    0;1;0.5
 3   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;0;0;0.5
 4   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;1;0;0.5
 5   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  0;1;0;0.5
 6   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI                 >;>;>     126;29;29.7    0;0;0.5 
 7   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  1;1;1;0.5
 8   PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant   >;>;>;>   126;29;29.7;6  0;0;0;0.5
```

with this code:

```
>>> def row_to_tree(row):
...     out = {}
...     pos = [out]
...     for cues, directions, thresholds, exits in zip(*map(lambda x: x.split(";"), row[["cues", "directions", "thresholds", "exits"]].values)):
...             pos = pos[0]
...             pos["cues"] = cues
...             pos["directions"] = directions
...             pos["thresholds"] = thresholds
...             pos["exits"] = exits
...             pos["children"] = [{"cues":True}]
...             pos = pos["children"]
...     pos.append({"cues": False})
...     return out
```

I can get this desired output:

```
>>> trees = [row_to_tree(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]
>>> print(json.dumps(trees[0], indent=2))
{
  "cues": "PLC2hrOGTT",
  "directions": ">",
  "thresholds": "126",
  "exits": "1",
  "children": [
    {
      "cues": "Age",
      "directions": ">",
      "thresholds": "29",
      "exits": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "cues": "BMI",
          "directions": ">",
          "thresholds": "29.7",
          "exits": "1",
          "children": [
            {
              "cues": "TimesPregnant",
              "directions": ">",
              "thresholds": "6",
              "exits": "0.5",
              "children": [
                {
                  "cues": true
                },
                {
                  "cues": false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but I want now to add an if statement inside this loop, so what I want now when I add the children I want an if there so that if the exits==1 first add True and then the child and if it's not then first add the child and then add False. (i.e. the parent 'PLC2hrOGTT' should have "cues": True and then "cues": "Age" because "exits": is "1" in 'PLC2hrOGTT) Can I achieve this in this loop?

This is the desired output:

```
{
    "cues": "PLC2hrOGTT",
    "directions": ">",
    "thresholds": "126",
    "exits": "1",
    "children": [
      {
        "cues": "True",
      },
      {
        "cues": "Age",
        "directions": ">",
        "thresholds": "29",
        "exits": "0",
        "children": [
          {
            "cues": "BMI",
            "directions": ">",
            "thresholds": "29.7",
            "exits": "1",
            "children": [
              {
                "cues": "True",
              },
              {
                "cues": "TimesPregnant",
                "directions": ">",
                "thresholds": "6",
                "exits": "0.5",
                "children":[
                  {
                    "cues": "True"
                  },
                  {
                    "cues": "False"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cues": "False"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: then after second child should by False? Don't quite understand your explanation what you try to achieve ..

Comment: No I want to see if `exits: "0"` then it should be False, if `exits: "1"` then True.

Comment: in what position should by 'False' or 'True' placed?

Comment: When True it should be placed first and if False it should be placed after the other cue.

Comment: then in you desired output "cues": "False" should by placed after BMI child?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are right. I think it is already placed like that, in my desired output !?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi What is your opinion? Is there a way to work around this, or should I completely change my approach?

Comment: @poweredbgt why is there True and False after last child? It is related to 0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want is needed to create two dictionaries to collect data and relocate input elements according to conditions. By the way You use nice trick with nesting dictionary. Descriptions in code.

=^..^=

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import json


data = StringIO("""
tree cues directions thresholds exits
1 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6 1;0;1;0.5
2 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI >;>;> 126;29;29.7 0;1;0.5
3 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6 1;0;0;0.5
4 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6 1;1;0;0.5
5 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6 0;1;0;0.5
6 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI >;>;> 126;29;29.7 0;0;0.5
7 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6 1;1;1;0.5
8 PLC2hrOGTT;Age;BMI;TimesPregnant >;>;>;> 126;29;29.7;6 0;0;0;0.5
""")

# load data into data frame
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=' ')


def row_to_tree(row):
    out = {}
    data = [{}, out]
    position = 1
    for cues, directions, thresholds, exits in zip(*map(lambda x: x.split(";"), row[["cues", "directions", "thresholds", "exits"]].values)):
        data = data[position]  # initialise dictionary
        # add elements to dictionary
        data['cues'] = cues
        data['directions'] = directions
        data['tresholds'] = thresholds
        data['exits'] = exits

        # add new empty dictionary at the end
        # handle dictionary starting position selection
        if int(float(exits)) == 1:
            position = 1
            data["children"] = [{"cues":True},{}]
        else:
            position = 0
            data["children"] = [{"cues":True},{"cues":False}]

        # relocate new dictionary to the end
        data = data["children"]

    return out

trees = [row_to_tree(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]
print(json.dumps(trees[0], indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "cues": "PLC2hrOGTT",
  "directions": ">",
  "tresholds": "126",
  "exits": "1",
  "children": [
    {
      "cues": true
    },
    {
      "cues": "Age",
      "directions": ">",
      "tresholds": "29",
      "exits": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "cues": "BMI",
          "directions": ">",
          "tresholds": "29.7",
          "exits": "1",
          "children": [
            {
              "cues": true
            },
            {
              "cues": "TimesPregnant",
              "directions": ">",
              "tresholds": "6",
              "exits": "0.5",
              "children": [
                {
                  "cues": true
                },
                {
                  "cues": false
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "cues": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution Zaraki! I found another solution before you posted, even though yours works as well.